# How to add attributes to SVG that might also be localized

Tags: c#, svg

I will start with the fact that I am no SVG expert.

As SVG is written in XML format, I wanted to know if exploiting this fact can assist me in addition to the convenience of the vector graphics it represents.
My issue is that I want to add some metadata to SVG, to make some of my code generalized, and additionally support different languages.

### Background:

We get SVG files from our UI experts - and for now, until our program will move to Windows 10 compile environment, we convert these SVGs to different sized PNG files, as required (SVG is supported from [Windows 10 build 15063](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource?view=winrt-19041#moniker-applies-to)).

Using the [SVG library from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/2.4.3):

```
static public void saveImageAsPng(string svgFullPath, string pngPath, int hight, int width)
{
    var doc = SvgDocument.Open(svgFullPath);
    doc.Width = hight;
    doc.Height = width;
    var bitmap = doc.Draw();

    bitmap.Save(pngPath, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

### Example

I have a folder with defined shapes:

[image]

Where I can add or remove shapes, as required.

I want now to use a dialog that lets you select a shape, and in each machine locale it should appear differently:
[image]

The Cirlcle.svg after translation to the three languages:

English (Full svg):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     height="24" width="24">
  <metadata>
     <DisplayType>Cirlcle</DisplayType>
  </metadata>
  <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

German:

```
:
  <metadata>
     <DisplayType>Kreis</DisplayType>
  </metadata>
:
```

Chinese:

```
:
  <metadata>
     <DisplayType>圈</DisplayType>
  </metadata>
:
```

### Questions

1. Is this the way to write metadata?
2. How do I access the metadata using the NuGet SVG library?
3. Is it a common practice to add data to SVG, that helps or even instruct the application using it, how to perform its task?

Comment: As you said SVG is XML format so you an use any Xml Library to read write the Xml.  I usually prefer to use Xml Linq.  Your metadata is just additional Xml tags that you want to add to the file and you can use any Xml Library.  I'm not sure if the NUGET SVG library will support adding custom tags, but xml linq does.

Comment: @jdweng  Actually you are right, I can even use System.xml to access the meta data, no need for any special tool. One worry I have: Does the svg schema allow any tag or info in its <metadata> (I am actually not familiar with the svg schema)?.

Comment: See following : https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#ForeignNamespaces